# Image object src never loads or creates an error message

Tags: javascript, image

I've been trying to work through this issue for an embarrassing amount of time and just cannot seem to wrap my head around why I cannot get it to work.

I have a function:

```
function createImage() {
  var imageObj = new Image();
  imageObj.onload = function() {    
    var item = new Konva.Image({
      x: 50,
      y: 50,
      image: imageObj,
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      draggable: true
    }); 
    addItem(item,cur_layer);  
  };
  imageObj.src = "img/p1.png";
}
```

The problem is that it seems like the source is never recognized, when that is the correct filepath to an image that exists. Even if the filepath is not a valid filepath, an error does not appear in the console saying invalid filepath. The code inside the onload is never executed.

I am unsure if this will help at all, but createImage() is called by:

```
function submit() {
  $('#screen').toggle();
  var type = $('#locator').val();
  console.log(type);
  var data;
  switch(type) {
    case "text":
      data = new Text();
      data.setValues($("input[name=Color]").val(), $("input[name=FontSize]").val(), $("input[name=FontFamily]").val(), $("input[name=Text]").val());
      data.print();
      createText(data);
      break;
    case "image":
      createImage();
      console.log(stage);
      break;
    case "rectangle":
      console.log("eh");
      data = new Rectangle();
      data.setValues($("input[name=Height]").val(), $("input[name=Width]").val(), $("input[name=Color]").val(), $("input[name=Border]").val(), $("input[name=BorderWeight]").val());
      data.print();
      createRecntagle(data);
      break;
    case "newPage":
      createNewPage($("input[name=pageName]").val(), $("#page_number").val());
      cur_layer = stage.children[$("#page_number").val()];
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
  prepare();
}
```

the case is image, the code goes through createImage(), but does nothing. Any help with this mystery will be much appreciated.

**EDIT**

I added the following code to the bottom of createImage(), and im still not getting the right results. This is just a local web app running on my machine without a server.

```
var img = new Image;

img.onload = function() {
    console.log("onload OK");
};
img.onerror = function() {
    console.log ("An error occured");
};
img.src = "some/file.jpg";

console.log("test");
```

My output to console was simply:

```
test
```

[image: network]

The hardcoded png files appear correctly.

```
            <div class="box"><img class="icon" id="add-item-tx" src="img/tx.png"></div>
        <div class="box"><img class="icon" id="add-item-sq" src="img/sq.png"></div>
```

Comment: What are you expecting your code to do? What does addItem() do?

Comment: addItem() is a method I need to execute once the item is created, the problem is that it never reaches this point.

Comment: What does the network tab in console say (F12)? For an error to be caught you'll need to add an onerror handler.

Comment: From your code you are creating the image dynamically, and not appending it to the DOM yet. See @jmagolisvt answer below.  And this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/GKFxP/3/) for a working example.

Comment: @Mekicha jmargolisvt's answer is wrong (see https://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/wa6swz0j/)

Comment: @K3N  So what's the difference here? https://jsfiddle.net/wa6swz0j/1/

Comment: Oh i see. Didn't know that. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @jmargolisvt the difference is that you haven't set a source yet. A src is needed to invoke loading - it has still a valid onload handler but nothing to trigger it.. OP *do* set a source (which I suspect is using a wrong path relative to document, server root, ie. /img/p1.png) but lets hear from OP what console says..

Comment: @jmargolisvt https://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/wa6swz0j/4/

Comment: Love it.  Thanks, @K3N.  I'll delete my answer then.  :)

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I've edited my post and tried several of these techniques but still am getting the same results.

Comment: @CDaly what does the **network** tab in console say? (ie. status code, response header). There are limitations to load files via file:// (not server hosted) in some browsers.

Comment: Just using chrome, added a screenshot to the original post.